# Form::model binding Laravel with <select multiple>

Tags: php, select, laravel, laravel-4, model-binding

I just discorvered that `Form::model` binding existed and I'm delighted with (it's wonderful). I tried it with text, email, and even select, every single time it worked.

My question is, will it work with a `<select multiple>`? If it does, how am I supposed to use it and what is the correct way to save an array in the database? (This may be awful but I concatenate all the options of the array with a separator and save it as text, I'm sure it's not the correct way to do it).

Comment: May this will help you.<br/>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17770581/multiple-select-edit-form-selected-values

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just like this :

```
Form::select('menus[]', $menus, null, array(
      'multiple' => true,
      'class' => 'form-control'
));
```

take a note :

param 1 : should be your field name (if want multiple add array tag aftrer field name e.g :`menus[]`)

param 2 : list menu (array) e.g : `array('value1' => 'text1', 'value2' => 'text2')`

param 3 : selected values. (should be `null` because `Form::model` will perform automatically matching values from database. **and make sure the field name has same with `key` data result from database**)

param 4 : is property for element `<select>` you can add class, id, and etc..

Comment: param 3, can also be Input::old('menus', array(1, 2) ), so in case of form error the data entered is not lost.

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa I never using Input::old instead Form::model more better for me :)